# WORKDAY formula shows correct value in Excel, but not in XML

Tags: excel, text

I am passing the formula `=TEXT(WORKDAY(TODAY(),1),"YYYYMMDD")` from an Excel to an XML which uses this final date (next working day) in trade creation.

This works fine if there are no weekends in between; but if tomorrow is Saturday/weekend - then on Excel it shows correct value (Monday) but the XML shows final value as 'Today-3' which is causing trade failures due to back-dates.

Can someone please advise how to overcome this issue?

Comment: "I am passing the formula =TEXT(WORKDAY(TODAY(),1),"YYYYMMDD") from an Excel to an XML ": How do you do that? Does the XML contains the formula after that? Or does it contains a string in "YYYYMMDD" format? If the first, how and from which software will the formula then be interpreted? If the latter and the value is wrong, then the code which puts the interpreted formula value into the XML is wrong. So we need to see that code.